# After Exponentials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, tetration

Look at this-
$$f(a,b)=a+b$$
The next step would be to make a function $g$ such that $$g(a,b)=\underbrace{a + a + a \cdots}_{b\text{ times}}=a\cdot b$$
Then we made $h$ so that $$h(a,b)=\underbrace{a\cdot a\cdots a}_{b\text{ times}}=a^b$$

With $f,g,h$ and their inverses, we can make a lot of equations. Would we ever make or use a function $j$ such that $$j(a,b)=\underbrace{a^{a^{a^{\cdots}}}}_{b\text{ times}}$$?

Comment: There aren't a lot of interestng *algebraic* properties of this function, but this function and it's further generalization are often used for large upper bounds and the like.

Comment: We sometimes write $j(a,b)=a\uparrow\uparrow b$. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation

Comment: This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: Oh wow Knuth's Notation is really good- a lot like what i was describing.

Comment: Graham's number. We need to upgrade math notation to express it. This video explains the notation you are looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTeJ64KD5cg

Comment: I vaguely recall Ramsey theory often has upper bound functions that group as fast or faster than this function.

Comment: This is called superexponentiation or power towers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function in question is called [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) or the [hyper $4$ operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation), its various notations are $^ba$, or $a\uparrow\uparrow b$, or $a\uparrow^{~2}b$ $($in [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation)$)$, and it has been studied ever since the time of Euler, who discovered that [infinite tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) converges for *x* in $\Big[e^{-e}~,~\sqrt[e]e\Big]$. More clearly, $~^{^\infty}\!\Big(\sqrt[a]a\Big)=\Big(\sqrt[a]a\Big)\uparrow\uparrow\infty=a$, for $a\in\bigg[\dfrac1e,e\bigg]$. The next operation in order is called pentation, followed by hexation, etc. Take the Greek numerals in order: tetra means four, penta is five, hexa six, etc. Their practical applications, however, are very few in number, albeit the related [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), used for expressing the solutions to $^2x=x\uparrow\uparrow2=x^x=y$, is gaining in popularity.